# Raspberry Pi GPIO stops working after some time

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspberry-pi2, gpio

when using the GPIO library on the Raspberry PI and having an example code like this:

```
while True:
    GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)
    pwm = GPIO.PWM(21, 50)
    pwm.start(0)

    for i in range(0, 101, 2):
        pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(i)
        time.sleep(0.03)
    for i in range(100, -1, -2):
        pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(i)
        time.sleep(0.03)

    pwm.stop()
    GPIO.cleanup(21)

    time.sleep(1)
```

The code might stop suddenly after a while. No error, just no changes via pwm are recognized any longer. Anyone got an idea why this is?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been mentioned here in the old sourceforge repo:

https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/tickets/111/

https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/tickets/94/

Its because the GPIO library by default creates a new pthread for every call without cleaning up afterwards, but the number of threads might be limited to a number of 250 or so.

I created a fork of this repo (https://github.com/wuestkamp/raspberry-gpio-python) which solves this and contains instructions on how to use this on your PI.